# How to send receive multiple responses from server corresponding to multiple requests from client using a suitable network protocol?

Tags: javascript, c#, http, tcp

I have an interactive visualization application where client-side (Javascript based) sends multiple requests for data and server-side (C# based) has to send response in the form of bytearrays corresponding to each request. The application can then use response bytearrays to create visualizations on client-side.

The design is such because the data is quite big for the client to handle at once. My browser crashes when server sends all the data at once to the client, so I have decided to use the aforementioned design.

Is there any way to support this functionality using HTTP or is it better to migrate to TCP?

Comment: What leads you to believe that this is a protocol - HTTP vs TCP - issue and not, for example, memory consumption issue? If it is indeed the size of all the data when packaged as a single response, whereas splitting the data in multiple fragments succeeds, then you can simply do multiple HTTP requests to get data fragments and reassemble on client-side.  How big is the response that makes it crash?  Does it crash all browsers?

Comment: It crashes on Chrome. The response is 4GB in size. I have tried fragmenting the data but the fragmenting scheme severely impacts interactivity when I shift from one fragment to another. So, I think sending small responses, processing, and visualizing them is a better idea (if my network protocol for transmission from server to client is robust enough to handle it). I might be wrong regarding this point though. Right now, the client is unable to hold, process and visualize all the response data and crashes.

Comment: I think we mean different things by fragmenting - in your definition, what's the difference between _small responses_ and _fragmenting_.  I meant that instead of single HTTP response to carry all data, make a series of requests/responses that each carries part of a larger response.  Also, are all 4GB of data needed to present a single view of data?  4GB is a lot and will take a long time for a page/view to load.  It doesn't surprise me that it pushes browsers to their limits (esp on 32bit systems).

Comment: Also, have you considered preprocessing raw data on the server so that client receives just the minimum necessary to visualize?  I.e. can 4GB be processed into a smaller dataset that is closer aligned to visualization needs?

Comment: But you can do the same on the server - what is the absolute minimum that the application needs?  When you say visualization - what does it mean exactly? Charts? Aggregated stats?

Comment: I use big responses on client side in the following way. Suppose, we have two big response bytearrays response1 and response2. The application should have the capability to add, subtract, multiply and divide (other user defined operations also possible) the two arrays elementwise. I was referring to the same way that you mentioned about making a series of requests and responses. But, these are not a part of larger response and can be used to show a visualization themselves.

Comment: All 4GB doesn't need to be present at the same time on the client-side and the fragmenting that we are referring to can probably help with that. I am unclear on how to do that though. If you know about any links or have any ideas for that, let me know. Preprocessing is a good idea. I have tried preprocessing the data too, but it confines me to a compressed version of data whereas I need to avoid compression because the data is meaningful in its original form. There might still be some way to go around with preprocessing probably.

Comment: The responses are supposed to show 1024X1024 Pixel images. These images are updated as the user queries about details regarding a region on earth. Since the images have to be updated quickly as the user explores a region, I try to perform a part of the array combination on client and a part on server. Finally, I combine them on the server and visualize them.

Comment: If you don't need all the data to visualize, then why push a whooping 4GB of it?  There's your answer - reduce data to only push what is necessary for the specific functionality at the moment.  In all honesty, pushing even a tenth of that size would be overly excessive.  I'm usually wary of APIs that return over a meg of data.

Comment: So 1024x1024 is exactly one meg of individual pieces of information.  Color map implies 3 or 4 bytes (depending if alpha channel is used) per unit (aka pixel) - that's 3-4MB total.  That is order**s** of magnitude smaller than your current data size.  So perhaps architecturally it's better to generate the image server-side and just push the image out? Note that 3-4MB would be an uncompressed bitmap; compress to PNG and you'll likely be down to a few hundred kilobytes.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, LB. I will try to modify my requests and responses for this purpose.

Comment: I would try to generate multiple PNG images out as responses to the requests by client based on the region that he queries for.

Comment: B/w, if you're currently using canvas or svg - you can still do the same - just send the minimal data necessary to update canvas or svg.... just precompute and reduce just for client needs (i.e. just pure final or near-final data).